# VBA: send email from remote excel using local outlook

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I am trying to solve is that I want Excel to send an email through Outlook. This is worked fine when I am using a local installation of Excel.
However I need to be able to do the same using an installation of Excel on a server. The debugger points to this line in the code:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "localcomputername")
```

At first I tried without reference to local computer this gave me error:

Runtime Error 429 - ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

With the line above I get the following errormessage:

Runtime error 463 - class not registered on local machine

Hope someone can help me

Comment: Did you write the VBA code that you're running locally?  Have you enabled the correct VBA libraries on the remote machine? In the visual basic editor go to tools > References.  I think you'll need Microsoft Office, OLE Automation, and maybe Microsoft Outlook checked.

Comment: http://www.devhut.net/2014/10/31/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the New operator or the **CreateObject** function in Microsoft Visual Basic to create an instance of a Microsoft Office application, you may receive the following error message:

*Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object*

This error occurs when the Component Object Model (COM) cannot create the requested Automation object, and the Automation object is therefore unavailable to Visual Basic. This error does not occur on all computers.

View this for More information - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/828550

Comment: It also gives this error if the target application is **not installed** on the machine creating the object.  Worth checking the remote machine actually has Outlook installed...